# Set QButton height

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside, maya

I probably should post this in multiple questions.

I need to know two things, I have a simple window that all it has is a button within it, set like so:

`self.spherize = QtGui.QPushButton("Spherize")`

I'm just wondering how to set the height of this button?

I've tried the following but it didn't work:

`self.spherize.setHeight(50)`

Also, where can I find propper docs for things like this with example code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [PyQT documentation for `QPushButton`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qpushbutton.html), but it inherits from [`QAbstractButton`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qabstractbutton.html) and [`QWidget`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qwidget.html) which has the methods for changing widget size.

The call you want is [`QWidget.setFixedHeight`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qwidget.html#setFixedHeight). So you want something like:

```
self.spherize.setFixedHeight(50)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [PySide](http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/) documentation.